# I have a problem with default fonts

Tags: fonts, lyx

I like to use large fonts when typing with LyX, but every time I press return it goes back to a small font. Can anyone help?

Comment: "press return" implies you are typing in to some editor, but you do not say which. Are you asking about the fonts in the final pdf, or the fonts in your editor display while typing the tex markup?

Comment: Sorry, no I was asking the question  about LyX

Comment: please edit your question so it is understandable no one would have guessed that was a question about lyx (I don't even have that installed)

Comment: @EstherBeneish So what you want are large letters on the screen, but not larger letters on the PDF that will be produced by LyX?

Comment: @EstherBeneish I can't reproduce this on LyX on Ubuntu. Can you please give detailed steps for exactly what you're talking about like you're describing it to a 5 year-old? screen-shots (e.g. before/after you press return) help also. Ping me with `@` after you do that.

Comment: @KeksDose   Yes that is exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: @scottkosty Just simply "press return". I am typing an AMS article. Not sure what else to say

Comment: @EstherBeneish Ah I see what you mean now. I suggest you make a request on http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: @scottkosty Do you mean this is a bug? (I don't understand what's happening, sounds to me like Esther is just after Ctrl + scrolling)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I did not think it was a bug but I thought it might be a valid enhancement request. I don't know what the user should expect in this case. I agree that ctrl+return is a good suggestion.

Comment: @EstherBeneish Does  Torbjørn T. 's suggestion of ctrl+return answer your question?

Comment: @scottkosty I didn't suggest Ctrl + enter (which you in general don't want to do in normal text), I suggested "zooming in" by holding Ctrl and scrolling the mouse wheel. Esther says she wants larger fonts in LyX, without making them larger in the PDF (see comment to Keks Dose above), which is what ctrl-scroll would do. I think perhaps Esther was setting the fontsize via right click->text style.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for clarifying that, I've done a sloppy job of reading this question and comments. I agree that ctrl+scroll is the way to go. Also note that this can be changed in Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Screen Fonts.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Thank you very very much, what worked was Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Screen Fonts. The other suggestions did not work. You have saved me a lot of aggravation

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments:

To change the size of the font as displayed in LyX, there are two possibilities:

1. Hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (possibly <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Mac) while scrolling with mouse/trackpad. The cursor has to be inside the text area, not over the menus/toolbars.
2. Go to Tools --> Preferences --> Look & Feel --> Screen fonts.

These are *not* the same as right-clicking in the text and changing the paragraph settings. That option is for changing the font size of the *output*, the PDF, while the above only changes how it's displayed in LyX.